# fatal error lnk1171 unable to load mspdbcore.dll (error code 126)

Tags: windows-10, command-line, opencl

i'm very new in OpenCL development and i'm trying to use Microsoft visual studio 2019.

i'm following [DE1-SoC OpenCL User Manual](http://DE1-SoC%20OpenCL%20User%20Manual) and [DE2 Development and Educational Board User Manua-DE1SOC_OpenCL_v02](http://download.terasic.com/downloads/cd-rom/de5a-net/linux_BSP/E1/DE5ANET_E1_OpenCL_17.1.pdf) to add the environment variables.

And when i try to compile the .cl file using the Command prompt using:

```
aoc -march=emulator -v -board=de1soc_sharedonly device/vector_add.cl -o bin/vector_add.aocx
```

and the resualt is

> Compiler Command: aoc -march=emulator -v -board=de1soc_sharedonly device/vector_add.cl -o bin/vector_add.aocx
>   c:/Users/marwe/Documents/opencl/exm_opencl_vector_add_x64_windows/exm_opencl_vector_add_x64_windows/vector_add/device/vector_add.cl:23:48: warning: declaring kernel argument with no 'restrict' may lead to low kernel performance
>   __kernel void vector_add(__global const float *x, 
>                                                  ^
>   c:/Users/marwe/Documents/opencl/exm_opencl_vector_add_x64_windows/exm_opencl_vector_add_x64_windows/vector_add/device/vector_add.cl:24:48: warning: declaring kernel argument with no 'restrict' may lead to low kernel performance
>                            __global const float *y, 
>                                                  ^
>   2 warnings generated.
>   Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.16.27031.1
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> LINK : fatal error LNK1171: unable to load mspdbcore.dll (error code: 126)

even though the desired file does exist.

please guide me through this.